# SQL Server 2014 temp variable update performance

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

Okay, so I have a query that looks like this:

```
Declare @Table1 Table (some columns)

Insert into @Table1 [QueryA]

Update @Table1 
set Field1 = A.Value1 
from ([QueryB]) A
where Field2 = A.Value2

Select * from @Table1
```

`QueryA` is a simple query that returns ~150 rows. `QueryB` is more complex and returns 3 rows. When run on its own, `QueryB` returns in less than 1 second. When run inside of the update statement, `QueryB` takes about 1 minute to run.

Now, if the query is reformatted like this, the whole thing takes less than a second:

```
Declare @Table1 Table (some columns)

Insert into @Table1 [QueryA]

Declare @Table2 Table (some columns)

Insert into @Table2 [QueryB]

Update @Table1 
set Field1 = A.Value1 
from (select * from @Table2) A
where Field2 = A.Value2

Select * from @Table1
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? My guess is that something wonky is going on with the optimizer engine, but if I'm missing something, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: You might want to look at the execution plan.

Comment: And maybe post it too.

Comment: The execution plan looks basically the same between the two versions of the query (posting it would be difficult due to the fact that QueryB is relatively complex).

Comment: Probably the estimated rows from the table variable are 1 and it executes QueryB 150 times. You can add `option (recompile)` to get it to take account of the true number of rows in the table variable.

Answer (score -2):

SQL Server does not create statistics on table variables so the query plans will involve scans, lots and, lots of repeated scans. The other this does not save the query plan so on every run through it recreates the query plan.
So what you are getting is scan for every row * (recreate a query plan +execute a query plan).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The thing that makes me question if this is what is happening is that if I use a left outer join instead of the update (with an isnull in the select) the whole thing takes less than a second.  I would think that if what you were saying was what was happening that I would see the poor performance with the left outer join as well.  Given the time it is taking to execute, it does feel like it is doing table scans, but I still don't understand why changing it to the left outer join would make that much of a difference.